# How to include Bibliography in TOC?

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents

I have problem with adding the {Bibliography} to the table of content. I have tried \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} but it appears at the top of TOC not at the bottom.

Comment: Where did you write in the code?

Comment: just after the command \tabelofcontent

Comment: Try writing it just after the code for the bibliography.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help…

Comment: Depending on your setup, you might be interested in the `tocbind` package which handles exactly this. Note that adding `\addcontentsline` just after he bibliography code only gives you the correct page number if the bibliography fits on a single page, otherwise it will point at the last page. The mentioned package hooks into the bibliography it self and adds it at the start.

Comment: @daleif or `\clearpage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}\printbibliography`

Comment: @Skillmon why? See esdds answer

Comment: @daleif because this works independently to  any package and for arbitrary long bibliographies. Of course, there might be other solutions, some of which more suitable (see esdds answer), but none working in any/every case (at least to my knowledge).

Answer (score 14):

There is the `biblatex` tag in the question. So maybe you can use

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Example}
\lipsum
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]%<- add a ToC entry for the bibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How to tell LaTeX to also add a letter or number in front of the BIBLIOGRAPHY entry at the TOC?
In my document it's automatically assigning letter to each entry belonging to sections...  but not to the bibliography.
I'm just using this
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={BIBLIOGRAFÍA}]

Comment: @skan Use `heading=bibnumbered`, see the documentation of package `biblatex`.